# Closure of set in $\mathbb{R}$ with standard metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Let
$$
A = \left\{ \frac{mn}{m^2 + n^2 + 1} : m, n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}.
$$
What is the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with standard metric?

So I know it contains $A$ itself but from there I don't know how to proceed. I may need just an hint, because I can't really see how this set is actually "made", meaning I can't really fully visualize it.

Comment: I don't know why this has formatting issues

Comment: It should be ok now

Comment: look's like pythagorean triplets : $(2mn,m^2+n^2,m^2-n^2)$...

Comment: $A=\left\{\dfrac{q}{q^2+q+1}\,:\,q\in \mathbb{Q}\right\}\cup \{0\}.$ So the basic question is: which rational numbers do we get for $q+\frac{1}{q}+1$?

Comment: @MariusS.L. I'm not sure I fully understand how you got there

Comment: Marius S.L. is defining $q=\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AnuragA I get $\frac{q}{q^2+1+1/n^2}$ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AnuragA Sorry, I forgot to divide $1$ by $mn.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Marius S.L.'s idea.

Given a rational number $q=\frac a b$, let $m=ak$ and $n=bk$ and then
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{akbk}{a^2k^2+b^2k^2+1}=\frac{q}{q^2+1}.$$
Let $B=\{\frac q{q^2+1}| q\in\Bbb Q\}$.

Then $B\subset\bar A$ and so $\bar B\subset\bar A$. Clearly, $\bar B=[-\frac12,\frac12].$ Therefore, $[-\frac12,\frac12]\subset\bar A.$
Since $A\subset [-\frac12,\frac12]$, $\bar A=[-\frac12,\frac12]$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much